# Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ

Tags: r, quantmod, gam, mgcv

On running a gam model using the mgcv package, I encountered a strange error message which I am unable to understand:

> “Error in model.frame.default(formula = death ~ pm10 + Lag(resid1, 1) +  :   variable lengths differ (found for 'Lag(resid1, 1)')”.

The number of observations used in model1 is exactly the same as the length of the deviance residual, thus I think this error is not related to difference in data size or length.

I found a fairly related error message on the web [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Lm-function-Error-in-model-frame-default-td3933466.html), but that post did not receive an adequate answer, so it is not helpful to my problem.

Reproducible example and data follows:

```
library(quantmod)
library(mgcv) 
require(dlnm)

df <- chicagoNMMAPS
df1 <- df[,c("date","dow","death","temp","pm10")] 
df1$trend<-seq(dim(df1)[1]) ### Create a time trend
```

### Run the model

```
model1<-gam(death ~ pm10 + s(trend,k=14*7)+ s(temp,k=5),
data=df1, na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
```

#### Obtain deviance residuals

```
resid1 <- residuals(model1,type="deviance")
```

#### Add a one day lagged deviance to model 1

```
model1_1 <- update(model1,.~.+ Lag(resid1,1),  na.action=na.omit)

model1_2<-gam(death ~ pm10 + s(trend,k=14*7)+ s(temp,k=5) + Lag(resid1,1), data=df1, 
na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
```

Both of these models produced the same error message.

Comment: (Almost) never think that an error message is flat out lying. That will greatly increase the amount of time you spend debugging it. Note that you've specified `na.omit`. Perhaps the differing lengths are due to an observation with an NA value being dropped.

Comment: @joran, the error occurs with or without the "na.omit" option. In fact my initial attempt was without specifying this option

Comment: The default (in most cases) is still `na.omit`. Note that `df` has 5114 rows and the length of `resid1` is only 4863. NA values are indeed being dropped. Try dropping the NA values _first_. Then your residual vector will match your original data frame.

Comment: @joran, many thanks for your suggestion. The model runs after I removed all NAs on outcome and predictors.

Comment: Feel free to write up what you did as an answer and (after the waiting period) accept it! :) Glad it worked out...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Joran suggested to first remove the NAs before running the model. Thus, I removed the NAs, run the model and obtained the residuals. When I updated model2 by inclusion of the lagged residuals, the error message did not appear again.

#### Remove NAs

```
df2<-df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

### Run the main model

```
model2<-gam(death ~ pm10 + s(trend,k=14*7)+ s(temp,k=5), data=df2, family=poisson)
```

### Obtain residuals

```
resid2 <- residuals(model2,type="deviance")
```

### Update model2 by including the lag 1 residuals

```
model2_1 <- update(model2,.~.+ Lag(resid2,1),  na.action=na.omit)
```

Answer (score 7):

Another thing that can cause this error is creating a model with the centering/scaling standardize function from the arm package -- `m <- standardize(lm(y ~ x, data = train))`

If you then try `predict(m)`, you get the same error as in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple, just make sure the data type in your columns are the same. For e.g. I faced the same error, that and an another error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
>     contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

So, I went back to my excel file or csv file, set a filter on the variable throwing me an error and checked if the distinct datatypes are the same. And... Oh! it had numbers and strings, so I converted numbers to string and it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking this question, you might have put your variable in quotation marks by accident. Do not put the variables in strings in R.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be a variable with the same name as the column. The formula won't know which one (variable or column) to take. Check the list of variables via `ls()` (or in RStudio) and use `remove(<varname>`) to remove if such a conflicting variable exists.