# Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : variable lengths differ (found for 'z')

Tags: r, model.matrix

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19771284/5967807) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29220727/5967807), but without helpful answers for my problem. I have no missing data in my dataset and am trying to created a `model.matrix` from a `model.frame`. Here is an reproducible example:

```
dat = data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 5), 
    y = rnorm(15), 
    z = rep(c(1,1.1,1.3), each = 5))
# this works
mt = model.matrix(model.frame(lm(y ~ x,dat)))
# this produces the error
mt = model.matrix(model.frame(lm(y ~ x + z,dat)))
```

Why and how to fix this? Alternatively, how can I obtain a matrix of right-hand side values with the intercept column in another, yet effective and robust way?

Comment: `mt = model.matrix(model.frame(lm(y ~ x,dat)))` don't run.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 is right, that line of code doesn't run as you've written it. That's because you need to look at `help("model.matrix")` to see which arguments the function expects; you need a formula or terms object as the first argument. Try `model.matrix(y ~ x + z, model.frame(lm(y ~ x + z, dat)))`.

Comment: `model.matrix` has default and lm methods.  For the first write it as `model.matrix(y ~ x + z, dat)` or if you need to write it as a function of the `lm` object then `model.matrix(lm(y ~ x + z, dat))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `model.matrix()` expects a formula or terms object as the first argument. Solution:

```
model.matrix(y ~ x + z, model.frame(lm(y ~ x + z, dat)))
```