# Variable lengths differ when plotting data

Tags: r

```
attach(auto)
The following object is masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:

    cylinders

The following objects are masked from auto (pos = 3):

    acceleration, cylinders, displacement, horsepower, mpg, name, origin,
    weight, year


plot(cylinders, mpg)

>Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Comment: Could you add where `auto` is from and/or add a sample of it with `dput`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771284/error-in-model-frame-default-variable-lengths-differ)

Comment: Also when i use plot(cylinders) , plot(mpg) separately, it is working

Comment: "Auto" is a data file that i took from ISL book's website. I had used the same commands before, it was working fine. Then my Rstudio got stuck. So i saved, closed my Rstudio and started working again from where i had left. Now i am getting these errors that i had mentioned

Comment: Okay i used rm(list=ls()). Then again loaded the data file using attach(). Now it is working fine