# Issue when running ns(variable, i) over a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nlme

I run the following loop to print a model for each index as a `ns(x, df=j)`

```
library(splines)
library(nlme)

# Generate some data
x <- 1:100
xid <- sort(rep.int(1:10, 10))
y <- x + rnorm(10)

# Loop through the number of knots in the spline
for (j in 1:5) {
  
  # Fit a spline with j knots
  fit <- lme(y ~ ns(x, j), random = ~1|xid)
  
  # Print the summary of the fit
  print(summary(fit))
}
```

I get the error message

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~y + x + j, data = <environment>,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'j')
```

I don't really understand why there's an issue and the error message doesn't show the `ns()` function. When doing this with a standard `lm` with no `xid` grouping structure, it works perfectly fine. There is something vaguely related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771284/error-in-model-frame-default-variable-lengths-differ) but doesn't look to be the same issue, only a similar error message. It's worth noting when I replace `j` with actual integers `1:5` it works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `j` is recognized as a variable instead of values 1 to 5. Therefore, we can use `as.formula` with `paste0` to turn `j` into numbers:

```
for (j in 1:5) {
  
  # Fit a spline with j knots
  #fit <- lme(y ~ ns(x, j), random = ~1|xid)
  fit <- lme(as.formula(paste0("y~ns(x,",j,")")), random = ~1|xid)
  
  # Print the summary of the fit
  print(summary(fit))
}
```